Help solving LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored
Downloaded TCmalloc yesterday when trying to install automatic1111. Didn't have any problems until starting my computer today, when I go the below error on startup. Also when ever I type anything into the terminal the error is echoed again. Ther is no libtcmalloc.so.4 in '/usr/lib/' but there is one located in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'. I also cannot find any reference to LD_PRELOAD, as per this advice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723666/error-ld-so-object-ld-preload-cannot-be-preloaded-ignored
On startup:
Error found when loading /etc/profile:
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
As a result, the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix th eproblem as soon as feasible
Terminal echo:
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

"Downloaded TCmalloc yesterday when trying to install automatic1111" presumably you followed some instructions to download / install /configure these? Can you provide links?

Some Ubuntu product & release details may also help (giving us clues as to your actual system's software stack)

Thank you for taking the time to reply, but I figured it out. For anyon eelse who sees this with a similar issue, I solved it by looking in /etc/enviroment and changing whatever LD_PRELOAD was incorrectly set as.
